# Extract specific path component in GNU parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

Given these files in `in/`,

```sh
$ find -type f | sort
./in/x/y/z1/i.jpg
./in/x/y/z2/i.jpg
./in/x/y/z3/i.jpg
./in/x/y/z4/i.jpg
./in/x/y/z5/i.jpg
```

I would like use GNU parallel to convert all JPEGs to PNGs, to create

```
./out/z1/png/i.png
./out/z2/png/i.png
./out/z3/png/i.png
./out/z4/png/i.png
./out/z5/png/i.png
```

My non-working solution so far, where `<???>` should be the `zX` path component from the input path:

```sh
find -type f | parallel "convert {} /path/to/out/<???>/png/{/.}.png"
```

In GNU parallel, how to extract the n-th path component from the input path? I.e. how do I get the `zX` part from `./in/x/y/zX/i.jpg`?

**Update:** I do not want to export a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [perl expression replacement string](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Perl-expression-replacement-string)

```
find -type f | parallel 'echo convert {} /path/to/out/{= s:.*/([^/]*)/[^/]*:\1: =}/png/{/.}.png'
```

prints

```
convert ./in/x/y/z1/i.jpg /path/to/out/z1/png/i.png
convert ./in/x/y/z2/i.jpg /path/to/out/z2/png/i.png
convert ./in/x/y/z3/i.jpg /path/to/out/z3/png/i.png
convert ./in/x/y/z4/i.jpg /path/to/out/z4/png/i.png
convert ./in/x/y/z5/i.jpg /path/to/out/z5/png/i.png
```

If this is what you want, then remove the `echo`.

Comment: Thank you @Socowi, exactly what I was looking for!